# how to know if a value is in the same range of time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    date    name
0   2019    a
1   2019    b
2   2019    c
3   2020    b
4   2020    c
5   2021    b
6   2021    c
```

I need to get the list of names that appears in 2019, 2020 and 2021 at the same time, in this case, should be:

```
[b,c]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If not, you can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: maybe `groupby(name)` and check which name has all dates. Or maybe simply count all names and get names which have 3 elements in column.

Comment: @furas I tried that but it returns `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fada2ee66d0>` and count will not work for my real thing as it could be repeated more than once in the same year

Comment: If you need help with *your* code, then you have to post it.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: what did you try to do with these groups? You can't only run `groupby` and expect results. You have object which has many functions and you have to use them. How about `df.groupby('name').count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by name, next count values and filter results which have count `3` (because you have 3 years)

```
groups = df.groupby('name').count()
result = groups[ groups['date'] == 3 ].index.to_list()

print(result)
```

Or you could directly count names

```
counts = df['name'].value_counts()
result = counts[ counts == 3 ].index.to_list()

print('result:', result)
```

---

Minimal working example:

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file.

```
text = '''    date    name
0   2019    a
1   2019    b
2   2019    c
3   2020    b
4   2020    c
5   2021    b
6   2021    c
'''

import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

counts = df['name'].value_counts()
result = counts[ counts == 3 ].index.to_list()
print('result:', result)

groups = df.groupby('name').count()
result = groups[ groups['date'] == 3 ].index.to_list()
print('result:', result)
```

---

**BTW:**

Instead of hardcoded value `3` you could count unique date

```
years = df['date'].unique()
print(years, len(years))
```

Result

```
[2019 2020 2021] 3
```

And this way you could use `len(years)` in place of `3`

---

**EDIT:**

If values can repeate then you can use `unique()` in group to remove repeated values.

```
text = '''    date    name
0   2019    a
1   2019    b
2   2019    c
3   2020    b
4   2020    c
5   2021    b
6   2021    c
7   2019    a
8   2019    a
'''

import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

groups = df.groupby('name')
#counts = groups['date'].unique().apply(len)
counts = groups['date'].nunique()
result = counts[ counts == 3 ].index.to_list()
print('result:', result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What happens when the value is repeated more than once in the same year, for example:

Comment: you could get `.unique()` values to skip repeated values. I will add example which gets unique years

Comment: oh ok let me try that, sorry I am new on this! :)

Comment: I used this `groups = df.groupby('name').nunique()
result = group.query('date == 3').index.tolist()
result` and it worked thanks!!!!